# Create check digit function

Tags: python, algorithm, barcode, check-digit

I'm trying to create check digits and append them after the original UPCs. Here's the [sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEqyJ.png)

Because there are leading 0's, I have to read the data as strings first:

```
import pandas as pd                                                                 
upc = pd.read_csv("/Users/lee/Desktop/upc.csv", dtype = str)
```

Here's an example of the check digit algorithm:
**If upc is 003459409000**
step (1) `0 + 3*0 + 3 + 3*4 + 5 + 3*9 + 4 + 3*0 + 9 + 3*0 + 0 + 3*0 = 60`
step (2) `60 mod 10 = 0`
step (3) `check digit = 0 (if it's not 0, then check digit = 10 - number in step 2)`

**Based on the algorithm, here's the code:**

```
def add_check_digit(upc_str):  
    upc_str = str(upc_str)
    if len(upc_str) != 12: 
        raise Exception("Invalid length")

    odd_sum = 0
    even_sum = 0 
    for i, char in enumerate(upc_str): 
        j = i+1 
        if j % 2 == 0: 
            even_sum += int(char) 
        else:
            odd_sum += int(char) 
    total_sum = (even_sum * 3) + odd_sum 
    mod = total_sum % 10 
    check_digit = 10 - mod 
    if check_digit == 10: 
    check_digit = 0 
    return upc_str + str(check_digit)
```

If I run this code, it gives correct check digit and appends this result to the end of the original UPC. For the example above, if I type:

```
add_check_digit('003459409000')
```

The output gives 13-digit UPC `0034594090000`.

**Now my questions are:**

1. This function works only for a single upc, i.e., I have to copy/paste each single upc and get the check digit. How do I create a function that works for a list of UPSs in a dataframe? Each result should return a 13-digit UPC with the check digits appended after the original UPC.
2. The UPCs are read as strings. How do I apply the function to the UPCs? I suppose I should convert the strings to numbers somehow.
3. After I get the new UPCs, how do I save the result in a csv file?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; we need your question to be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Comment: Sorry. I was having trouble publishing my code earlier. I just edited my post with original code.

Comment: thanks for posting the detail. try the answer provided for this question.

Comment: Please edit your code; it still can't execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data set up for me as I don't have CSV file, below step is the same as your

```
df = pd.read_csv("/Users/lee/Desktop/upc.csv", dtype = str)
```

**data setup**

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({"upc_in_file":['003459409000','003459409001','003459409002']})
```

```
def add_check_digit(upc_str):  
    upc_str = str(upc_str)
    if len(upc_str) != 12: 
        raise Exception("Invalid length")

    odd_sum = 0
    even_sum = 0 
    for i, char in enumerate(upc_str): 
        j = i+1 
        if j % 2 == 0: 
            even_sum += int(char) 
        else:
            odd_sum += int(char) 
            total_sum = (even_sum * 3) + odd_sum 
            mod = total_sum % 10 
            check_digit = 10 - mod 
        if check_digit == 10: 
            check_digit = 0 
    return upc_str + str(check_digit)
```

apply the above function to the upc column(the one which was read from file)

```
df['new_upc']=df['upc_in_file'].apply(add_check_digit)
```

now save the file!

```
df.to_csv("my_updated_upc.csv")
```

this will look like [image]

Comment: It works like wonder!!!! Thank you very much! I should really start to learn python since it works better than R.

Comment: pls accept the answer so i get points lol . You are welcome :)

Comment: I believe I successfully checked yours as a correct answer. Your code is much simpler than a for loop.