# Pyspark: Check for conditions on each cell and calculate the checkdigit

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a column `RESULT` which has digits of length 11 in each and the schema of the same is:

```
RESULT: string (nullable = true)
```

[image]

Now, I want to perform the below operation and update a new column which will add an extra digit at last. The example shown below is for first number `03600024145`

**Note**: I don't want to change the format of table to pandas but do everything in Pyspark dataframe.

1. Add the odd number digits: 0+6+0+2+1+5 = 14.
2. Multiply the result by 3: 14 × 3 = 42.
3. Add the even number digits: 3+0+0+4+4 = 11.
4. Add the two results together: 42 + 11 = 53.
5. To calculate the check digit, take the remainder of (53 / 10), which is also known as (53 modulo 10), and if not 0, subtract from 10. Therefore, the check digit value is 7. i.e. (53 / 10) = 5 remainder 3; 10 - 3 = 7.
6. Add this check digit at last. So the number becomes `036000241457`

So, if this logic is applied to the whole column the result will become as `UPDATED RESULT`

[image]

For further clarification of logic :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_digit#UPC

There is a similar python code but a bit different at step-5: [python: create check digit function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67341806/python-create-check-digit-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can translate the logic as Spark functions.

1. First extract numbers at various positions and cast them to integers.
2. Then sum odd and even positions separately.
3. Multiply odd sum by 3 and add the even sum.
4. Apply modulo operation.
5. Subtract 10 by result from step 4 and then apply modulo 10, to imitate behavior of check digit being 0 when result from step 4 is 0.
6. Finally, concatenate `RESULT` column with the `check digit`.

## Working Example

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Column
from typing import List

df = spark.createDataFrame([("03600024145",), ("01010101010",)], ("RESULT",))

def sum_digits(c: Column, pos: List[int]):
    sum_col = F.lit(0) 
    for p in pos:
        sum_col = sum_col + F.substring(c, p, 1).cast("int")
    return sum_col

def check_digit(c: Column) -> Column:
    odd_sum = sum_digits(c, [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11])
    even_sum = sum_digits(c, [2, 4, 6, 8, 10])
    sum_result = (3 * odd_sum) + even_sum
    modulo  = sum_result % 10
    return (10 - modulo) % 10    

df.withColumn("UPDATED_RESULT", F.concat(F.col("RESULT"), check_digit(F.col("RESULT")))).show()
```

### Output

```
+-----------+--------------+
|     RESULT|UPDATED_RESULT|
+-----------+--------------+
|03600024145|  036000241457|
|01010101010|  010101010105|
+-----------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution using user defined function (udf).

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col

df = spark.createDataFrame([('03600024145',), ('01010101010',)], ['RESULT'])

@udf(StringType())
def add_check_digit(val):
    odd = sum(int(i) for i in val[::2])
    even = sum(int(i) for i in val[1::2])
    check_val = (odd * 3 + even) % 10
    
    return val + str((10 - check_val) % 10)

df = df.withColumn('UPDATED_RESULT', add_check_digit(col('RESULT')))

df.show()

+-----------+--------------+                                                    
|     RESULT|UPDATED_RESULT|
+-----------+--------------+
|03600024145|  036000241457|
|01010101010|  010101010105|
+-----------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the column `RESULT` into an array of digits than using some  higher order functions `transform` and  `aggregate`, you can calculate the `checkdigit` that you concatenate to the original string:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "digits",
    F.expr("slice(split(RESULT, ''), 1, size(split(RESULT, '')) - 1)")
).withColumn(
    "digits",
    F.expr("transform(digits, (x, i) -> struct(int(x) as d, i+1 as i))")
).withColumn(
    "odd_even",
    F.expr(
        """aggregate(digits, 
                     array(0, 0), 
                     (acc, x) -> 
                         IF (x.i%2 = 1,
                             array(acc[0] + x.d, acc[1]),
                             array(acc[0], acc[1] + x.d)
                         )
        )""")
).withColumn(
    "UPDATED RESULT",
    F.concat(F.col("RESULT"), 10 - ((F.col("odd_even")[0] * 3 + F.col("odd_even")[1]) % 10))
).select(
    "RESULT", "UPDATED RESULT"
)

df1.show(truncate=False)

#+-----------+--------------+
#|RESULT     |UPDATED RESULT|
#+-----------+--------------+
#|03600024145|036000241457  |
#|01010101010|010101010105  |
#+-----------+--------------+
```

##### Explanations:

- **Step 1**: [split](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#split) the column and [slice](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#slice) the resulting array to remove the last empty value. Then [transform](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#transform) each element of the array by adding its index. (Example `0 -> struct(0, 1)`)
- **Step 2**: using [aggregate](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#aggregate), sum even and odd position digits by using the index we added in the first step
- **Step 3**: calculate the check digit and concatenate it with result column

You can show all the intermediate columns to understand the logic.